# warning: expression results unused

Tags: c++, warnings

Why does the compiler issue the `warning: Expression results unused` in the last `else` statement of this code?

```
PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility PowerballLottery::checkTicket(PowerballTicket ticket)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (ticket.getBall1() == getball1() || ticket.getBall1() == getball2() || ticket.getBall1() == getball3() || ticket.getBall1() == getball4() || ticket.getBall1() == getball5())
        count++;
    if (ticket.getBall2() == getball1() || ticket.getBall2() == getball2() || ticket.getBall2() == getball3() || ticket.getBall2() == getball4() || ticket.getBall2() == getball5())
        count++;
    if (ticket.getBall3() == getball1() || ticket.getBall3() == getball2() || ticket.getBall3() == getball3() || ticket.getBall3() == getball4() || ticket.getBall3() == getball5())
        count++;
    if (ticket.getBall4() == getball1() || ticket.getBall4() == getball2() || ticket.getBall4() == getball3() || ticket.getBall4() == getball4() || ticket.getBall4() == getball5())
        count++;
    if (ticket.getBall5() == getball1() || ticket.getBall5() == getball2() || ticket.getBall5() == getball3() || ticket.getBall5() == getball4() || ticket.getBall5() == getball5())
        count++;
    bool match = false;
    if (ticket.getPowerball() == getpowerball())
        match = true;
    if ((count == 0) && (match == false))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::NOTWINNING;
    else if ((count == 0) && (match == true))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::POWERBALL;
    else if ((count == 1) && (match == true))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::ONEPLUSPOWERBALL;
    else if ((count == 2) && (match == true))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::TWOPLUSPOWERBALL;
    else if ((count == 3) && (match == false))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::THREE;
    else if ((count == 3) && (match == true))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::THREEPLUSPOWERBALL;
    else if ((count == 4) && (match == false))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FOUR;
    else if ((count == 4) && (match == true))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FOURPLUSPOWERBALL;
    else if ((count == 5) && (match == false))
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FIVE;
    else ((count == 5) && (match == true));
        return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FIVEPLUSPOWERBALL;
}
```

Comment: with such an avalanche of mutually exclusive cases, it's no wonder the compiler detects some. You might want to use some arrays/vectors and loops to make this both easier to understand and less buggy.

Comment: IMO, this should not be closed as being a typo. As trivial as it might seem to some more experienced programmers, this isn't just a typo, or anything equally trivial either.

Comment: @JerryCoffin May be you're right. For me it looks somehow like that famous OpenSSL `goto fail;` bug. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 4):

Effectively, the code is

```
if ((count == 0) && (match == false))
....
else if ((count == 5) && (match == false))
    return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FIVE;
else
    ((count == 5) && (match == true)); //<- Expression results unused 

return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FIVEPLUSPOWERBALL;
```

Comment: I should not post it as an answer perhaps, but it would be hard to squeeze formatted code to a comment :).

Comment: _"OK, I just voted to close."_ You should note I've just changed my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out the problem the compiler was warning you about.

Now let's consider the problem it didn't warn you about: your code is much more complex than there's any good reason for it to be.

In essence, the users picks and the balls chosen in the lottery (other than the power-ball) form sets. What we care about is the size of the intersection of those two sets. The C++ standard library gives us tools to make that task a lot simpler (and it looks to me like the way you've designed your `PowerBallTicket` class is doing more to hinder than help too):

```
std::set<int> lottery { 
    getball1(), 
    getball2(), 
    getball3(), 
    getball4(), 
    getball5()
};

std::set<int> tick { 
    ticket.getball1(), 
    ticket.getball2(), 
    ticket.getball3(), 
    ticket.getball4(), 
    ticket.getball5() 
};

std::vector<int> matches;

std::set_intersection(lottery.begin(), lottery.end(), 
                      tick.begin(), tick.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(matches));
```

That gives us the matches between the two. From there, we have the problem of converting the number of matches (plus whether the Powerball matched) to choose which enumeration value to return. One easy way to do that is to is an array:

```
WinningPossibility rets[][6] = {
    { NOTWINNING, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE},
    { POWERBALL, ONEPLUS, TWOPLUS, THREEPLUS, FOURPLUS, FIVEPLUS }
};
```

With those in place, our return looks something like this:

```
return rets[ticket.getpowerball() == getpowerball()][matches.size()];
```

The code above points toward an improvement: instead of all those `getballX()` member functions, you should just store the data in a `set` to start with, and operate directly on those sets. In this case, it looks like you have [quasi-classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf), with  "encapsulation" that's losing a great deal, and gaining little (probably nothing).

Answer (score 2):

As said from [@AlexD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246555/alexd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35590295/1413395) this is primarily a problem with how you had formatted the code, and that warning appears because

```
else ((count == 5) && (match == true));
```

that statement actually isn't used to do any computation stored in a result, or making a branch decision based on it.

The

```
return PowerballLottery::WinningPossibility::FIVEPLUSPOWERBALL;
```

statement is executed regardless anyways.

---

Reminds a bit about the famous [apple *OpenSSL `goto fail;` bug*](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/):

> > ```
> > if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
> > goto fail;
> > goto fail;  /* MISTAKE! THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE HERE */
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

You can say `else <statement>` or `else if (<expression>) <statement>`; you have the expression without the `if`, which the compiler is doing its best with.